# How to install SQLiteStudio?

Tags: software-installation

There are two links for Linux: https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt?act=download

A portable version, which runs by clicking it.

And an installer version, which tells me the following thing by clicking it:

[image]

Comment: Try the lamp stack.

Comment: I need a good SQLite Client and therefore want to know how to install `SQLiteStudio` on Linux

Comment: did you follow the procedure of chmod'ding the file so it is executable or just download and try to execute it? If that latter: we take security serious so downloads are NEVER directly executable.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal in that directory and run the following commands:
`$ chmod +x Installer`
`$ ./Installer`

Comment: Do i always need to execute this in order to run the app?

Answer (score 0):

Or a GUI method would be to:

1. Right-click on the installer file.
2. Select "Properties" from the pop-up menu.
3. Click on the "Permissions" tab.
4. Check the "Execute: __ Allow executing file as program" box.
5. Click on the installer program again and select "Run" from the pop-up menu.

As a matter of preference, in windowing operating system interfaces, I prefer to download installers to my Downloads folder and create a sub-folder for the application. That way I know what the installer is for; no matter how obscurely it is named and I have all the installers for various versions of an application in one place.

In Ubuntu, I prefer to use apt or the Ubuntu Software app, but neither was an option for this particular program.